# RFC: Spirit Realm Investigation Results

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm not sure about you, but I'd like to know if Spirit Realm Investigator is going to issue a report something in Q3.  [Spirit Realm Investigator](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/50422/spirit-realm-investigator) seems to me like a modern day Vladimir I and I, for one would like to know if there's any answers have been gleaned that have helped in the investigation.

Comment: I am completely bumfuzzled here!

Comment: @KenGraham I'm just wondering if any headway is being made in the investigations of the Spirit Realm.  A person who asks nearly 200 questions must have some answers! I figure it's about time for a report on the investigation.

Comment: This post got flagged as  **opinion based** ! Sorry to close your question, but it seems opinion based to here!